# Photoshop cs6 unintentional cropping problem

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, borders, canvas

Elements in photoshop cs6 are being cropped if placed outside the canvas borders. So when I drag that layer elsewhere, the rest of the element is gone. Is there any way to stop this happening and to retain the entire element beyond the canvas borders?

Answer (score 1):

With the **Crop Tool** selected, uncheck the "Delete Cropped Pixels" option in the **Control Bar**.

[image]